# server exception, OperationCanceledException, occurs at Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContextExtensions.GetDependencyResolver

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api2

I have an api which I can call using this `cURL` command:

```
 C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer X.Y.Z -d '{
 >>    "Filter": {
 >>      "ShowRent": true,
 >>      "ShowSale": true,
 >>      "ShowApartment": true,
 >>      "ShowOffice": true,
 >>    },
 >>    "PageSize": 1,
 >>    "PageNumber": 1
 >>  }'  http://localhost:port_number/path_to_api
```

this request completes successfully.
The api is supposed to return a `List<ResultDto>`.
I want to create the same request, in a Xamarin project.
Here is what I've tried:

```
var a = new
    {
        PageSize = 5,
        PageNumber = 1,
        Filter = new
        {
            ShowRent = true,
            ShowSale = true,
            ShowApartment = true,
            ShowOffice = true
         }
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
    var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Bearer",
            my_access_token);
    var rawResponse = await client.PostAsync(
        "http://localhost:port_number/path_to_api",
        stringContent
        );

    List<RealtorEstateMarkerDto> result=
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultDto>>(
            await rawResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

when my xamarin code runs, `System.OperationCanceledException` exception occurs on the server.

Here is Stack Trace of the exception:

```
at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
at Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContextExtensions.GetDependencyResolver(IOwinContext context)
```

Comment: Minor difference I see is on Xamarin you're not setting the Accept header

Comment: You need to look at the entire exception/stacktrace as most likely the root cause will be within inner exception that you have not shown.

Comment: you also need to verify that your server is reachable from the device/emulator.  "localhost" addresses are problematic and you should usually use the server IP or FQDN instead